# Are postgres function arguments passed by reference or value?

Tags: postgresql

When I call a function and pass it an argument, is that argument's value actually copied in memory so that the called function receives a copy of the value, or it is passed a reference/pointer?

I guess in some cases it's obvious - I'd expect an integer to be copied, for example, but what if I have a large string or array or table row?

From my own observations it appears the value is always copied, because I can edit the value in the called function without changing the value in the calling function. In fact I can't think of any case where I've been able to modify something passed in as an argument, and have the calling function pick up the change without returning the changed data from the called function.

I'm always uneasy about passing large amounts of data from one function to another for this reason. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how postgres handles arguments, hence this question. The function types I use are SQL and plpgsql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the procedural language and the type.

**C functions**:

- Fixed length data types are passed by value if the `typbyval` column in `pg_type` is `TRUE`.
- Unless you configure PostgreSQL with `--disable-float4-byval`, `real` is passed by value.
- `bigint`, `double precision` and the `timestamp` types are passed by value on 64-bit architectures unless you configure PostgreSQL with `--disable-float8-byval`.

All other data types are passed by reference, and it is your responsibility not to modify the data (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-BASETYPE) and the source in `configure.in` and `src/include/postgres.h`).

**PL/pgSQL functions:**

All arguments are passed by value, because the following code in function `plpgsql_exec_function` in `src/pl/plpgsql/src/pl_exec.c` creates a copy:

```c
/*
 * Make local execution copies of all the datums
 */
estate.err_text = gettext_noop("during initialization of execution state");
copy_plpgsql_datums(&estate, func);
```

I didn't explicitly check the other procedural languages, but I'm quite certain that everything will be passed by value as well, since that data have to be converted to the internal representation of the respective programming language.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask how you know this? Is it documented somewhere, or a conclusion from reading the source code, or something else?

Comment: Ok, I checked, and it turns out that the answer is more complicated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe aren't functions exposed in c,(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-BASETYPE) and called in pgsql still  use pass by value?

Comment: also, if we return records in pgsql, the records are also copied for return?

Comment: @mleko That's a different question.